# Real time data from server using socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

I am trying to get realtime data that come from server where I have the URL `ws://xxx.xxx.xx.12/Geteventcntr/getUserMatchLst/4/696`

i do not know how to connect it to server and get data from respose

```
public class OddsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private OkHttpClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_odds);
        client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url("ws://xx.xx.xx.xx/Geteventcntr/getUserMatchLst/4/696").build();
        EchoWebSocketListener listener = new EchoWebSocketListener();
        WebSocket ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);
        client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();

    }

    private final class EchoWebSocketListener extends WebSocketListener {
        private static final int NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000;
        @Override
        public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
            output("Receiving : " + text);
        }
        @Override
        public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
            output("Receiving bytes : " + bytes.hex());

        }
        @Override
        public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
            webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, null);
            output("Closing : " + code + " / " + reason);

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response) {
            output("Error : " + t.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void output(String s) {
        Log.d("WebSocket", "output: "+s);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the reponse type? is it JSON, raw array, xml, or else?

Comment: json response , i have updated my code that i tried but got response
 Error : Expected HTTP 101 response but was '200 OK'
i am able to get data when i hit in browser

Comment: I can't give you an example, but I can give you a recommendation. I recommended you to use https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/, this SDK looks easy to use and well documented

Comment: You might want to examine the response in `onOpen()`,  and you might want to explain what is actually happening, what error messages or exceptions you receive, etc.

Comment: Error : Expected HTTP 101 response but was '200 OK'
@JamesKPolk  this is the error and i just want to receive data from server i have nothing done in     onOpen()  as i am not sending data from android,

Answer (score 0):

First add this line to your gradle

```
implementation 'com.neovisionaries:nv-websocket-client:2.4'
```

After implement it you have to create a class `WebsocketClient` to connect and get the real time data from the server.

```
    public class WebsocketClient {

    public static String url = "ws://XXX.XXX.XXX/XXX";
    private static WebSocketClient mWebSocketClient;

    public static void connect_to_server(Context con) {


        URI uri;
        try {
            uri = new URI("ws://XXX.XXX.XXX/XXX");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri, new Draft_17()) {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
                Log.e("Websocket", "Opened");

            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String s) {

                Log.e("OnMessageRecieved>>>",s.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int code, String s, boolean b) {
                Log.e("Websocket", code + ": Closed " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Log.e("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
            }
        };

        if(mWebSocketClient.getConnection().isConnecting()){

        }else{
            mWebSocketClient.connect();
        }
    }

}
```

And Connect to it from activity

```
WebsocketClient.connect_to_server(MainAtivity.this)
```

Comment: WebSocketClient  is not defined

Comment: `connect_to_server` is a static method so you can call it directly by class name

Comment: You don't need to define `WebSocketClient `

Comment: It showing define class as even after implementing the dependency